# Writing tests for AngularJS with UnderscoreJS

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, underscore.js, gruntjs, karma-runner

I started learning how to test Angular apps, and ran into some problems.

I generated an Angular app using Yeoman. `yo angular --minsafe AppName`

Then generated a service `yo angular:service MyService`

Wrote a simple method in the service, and a test for it, just to make sure that everything was working. I ran `grunt test` and the tests passed.

Now it gets interesting, as I added Underscore to the mix using `bower install underscore` and added a `<script>` tag for it in the `index.html`.
Then I added some simple code to the service method, just `_.map([1,2,3], function(el){return el+1});` to see if Underscore was working.

I ran the tests again `grunt test`, and it failed saying that `_ is not defined`.

I tought that, because Underscore attaches the _ variable to the window object, it would be available for the testing. Am I wrong?

Also, when I ran the application in the browser, Underscore was defined and working.

So, my question is, how do you test an Angular app that uses Underscore? Is this a common problem or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks,
Petar

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you see the `karma.conf.js` file generated by Yeoman, you will see that bower components are not added automatically.

```
// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files = [
  JASMINE,
  JASMINE_ADAPTER,
  'app/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
  'app/scripts/*.js',
  'app/scripts/**/*.js',
  'test/mock/**/*.js',
  'test/spec/**/*.js'
];
```

Just add the underscore folder to it and you won't have any issues.

Answer (score 1):

Using constants like `JASMINE` or `JASMINE_ADAPTER` is deprecated in Jasmine version before 2.0. Use `frameworks: ['jasmine']` in the `karma.conf.js` file instead.